# Get custom windows form button event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a customize windows form and I just don't know how should I get access to the button click event when the button is inside the custom form and the method is in the main windows application.

thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using WPF? WinForms? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: The method shouldn't be in the Main form.

Comment: but the method has nothing to do with the fontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form, create a custom event and make it fire whenever the button is pressed:

```
public event EventHandler TheButtonClicked;

// Constructor
public CustomWindow()
{
  theButton.Click += FireTheButtonClicked;
}

public void FireTheButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(TheButtonClicked != null) TheButtonClicked(this, e);
}
```

Now you have an event on your custom window that you can subscribe to from your main window.

Comment: thank you very much I succeeded to apply the button but if there are a few of these controls in a MyCustomControl list and I want each one of the same Button to do the same action but with a different sender how can i do it?